# How execute bash Command Substitution in npm script

Tags: bash, npm, tslint, npm-scripts

I want to execute linter only on staged files.

For this i wrote inside package.json the command(inside scripts):

```
"fix-lint": "tslint $(git diff --name-only --staged) "
```

Execute it:

```
npm run fix-lint
```

I have an error:

```
error: unknown option --name-only
```

I tried to figure out and try simple command:

```
"lss": "echo $(ls)"
```

And again execute it:

```
npm run lss
```

The result is printing $(ls) instead of printing all files in directory.

My question is how to fix this commands/scripts?
Or maybe in general how execute bash Command Substitution in npm script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `"fix-lint": "sh -c 'tslint $(git diff --name-only --staged)'"`

Comment: I can't believe!!! It works! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Just posting @jordanm comment to mark this question as resolved.</sup>

Use:

```
"fix-lint": "sh -c 'tslint $(git diff --name-only --staged)'"
```

To store the output of a command to a datestamped file, you can use `tee` and `date` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts | sh -c 'tee output/spec-reports/scan-$(date \"+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M\").txt'",
}
```

Comment: @jordanm, feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I'll remove mine.